# How to Loop through JavaScript object literal with objects as members in descending order

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, object, for-loop

```
for (var key in validation_messages) {
 var obj = validation_messages[key];
 for (var prop in obj) {
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
  alert(prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
  }
 }
}
```

This is the for loop that i have but i'm getting the response in ascending order. But i need it in descending order. Can some one help me.

Thanks

Comment: Iterating over an object *doesn't* return the properties in a predictable order; you could perhaps copy them to an array, and then sort/reverse that, though.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript does not guarantee a specific object property order, see this: [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

If you need a specific order, you should use an array.

If you had them in an array, the code would look like this(fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/DH3VQ/1/) :

```
var props = [
    { key:"p1", value:"a"},   
    { key:"p2", value:"b"},   
    { key:"p3", value:"c"},   
];

for (var i = 0; i< props.length; i++){
    alert(props[i].key + " = " + props[i].value);
}
```

Or you could do something fancier:

```
   props.forEach(function(prop){alert(prop.key + " = " + prop.value)});
```

But the standard for is probably more portable.

Comment: if it was an array, what would be the condition for the for-loop

Comment: Edited the answer, that's how you would use an array.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
Object.keys(validation_messages)
      .sort(function(a,b) {
           return b.localeCompare(a);
      })
      .forEach(function(key) {
           var val = validation_messages[key];

           console.log(key, val);
      });
```

`Object.keys` gets the enumerable properties of an object into an Array. Then the `.sort()` will sort them in descending order, and the `.forEach()` will iterate the sorted set of keys.

So then for each key, you can grab the value from the object, and use it.